# How to prevent bash alias from storing pid

Tags: bash

I have an alias which attaches process named myprocess in gdb.

i.e. alias myat="gdb /path/to/myprocess $(pgrep myprocess)"
$ type myat
myat is aliased to `gdb /path/to/myprocess 23313'

This will work until myprocess dies and restarts with a new pid.
But, to be able to use the alias again, I have to reload my ~/.bashrc

Is there a better way of specifying this alias, so that I don't need to reload
~/.bashrc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that bash expands substitutions within double quotes (`" "`) at the time the `alias ...` command is run. Either escape the substitution as `\$(...)`, or use single quotes (`' '`) instead.

```
alias myat="gdb /path/to/myprocess \$(pgrep myprocess)"
alias myat='gdb /path/to/myprocess $(pgrep myprocess)'
```

Or use a function instead:

```
myat() { gdb /path/to/myprocess $(pgrep myprocess); }
```